# Can I get non-shared objects via the service locator using an abstract factory?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I've been looking for a while now, but couldn't find how, or whether it's possible at all.

I have an abstract factory that by default gets me shared objects. Is there a way to tell the service locator to give me a new instance every time I request the service?

The shared config parameter only seems to work with *invokables* and `$serviceManager->setShared()` will also not work because the name of the service is never registered (hence the *abstract factory*).

Comment: add your code so we have something to star with

Comment: do you by chance want to do what initalizers do? http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.service-manager.intro.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default *all* services are shared, it make no difference *how* they are created.

The first call to `$serviceManager->get('foo')` will create the [instance of the service and then store that value in memory, keyed by it's canonical name](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php#L563).

The second call to `$serviceManager->get('foo')` will [match this stored value and return the *same* instance](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php#L516).

The obvious exception to the above is if you disable the 'shared by default' option on the service manager or specifically add a `false` value to the `shared` config key in `Module.php` or module config.

Comment: It seems I had tested this the wrong way before. Setting the 'shared' config key is sufficient.
cptnk gave me a nudge in the direction I'll go, by using $sm->setShared() in the DI initializer specifically on the class requested.